# Find Events that are succeeded at consecutive days in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, row-number

This is my input dataset

| event_date | event_name |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-06-01 | succeded |
| 2023-06-02 | succeded |
| 2023-06-03 | succeded |
| 2023-06-04 | failed |
| 2023-06-05 | failed |
| 2023-06-06 | failed |
| 2023-06-07 | succeded |

and this is output

| start_date | end_date | event_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-01 | 2023-06-03 | succeded |
| 2023-06-04 | 2023-06-06 | failed |
| 2023-06-07 | 2023-06-07 | succeded |

I was using min and max over event_name but that is not givign the right results.

I am on job hunt , and this tricky qiestion seems confusing

ANy help or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Provide **precise** MySQL version. PS. Search for "gaps and islands".

Answer (score 0):

> I was using min and max over event_name but that is not givign the right results.

You just need to find more suitable feature to `GROUP BY`. Something that not change in **every group** of consecutive `event_name`s.

In this case, this additional attribute is the date when the next `event_name` "started".

The correlated subquery will help you with this:

```sql
SELECT
  el.*,
  (
    SELECT event_date
    FROM eventlog
    WHERE event_date > el.event_date AND event_name != el.event_name
    ORDER BY event_date LIMIT 1
  ) as next_new_event_date
FROM
  eventlog el
ORDER BY el.event_date
```

As you see now, each group of consecutive `event_name`-s is clearly distinguishable.

And then it is a matter of technique:

```sql
SELECT
  min(event_date) as start_date,
  max(event_date) as end_date,
  any_value(event_name) as status
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    el.*,
    (
      SELECT event_date
      FROM eventlog
      WHERE event_date > el.event_date AND event_name != el.event_name
      ORDER BY event_date LIMIT 1
    ) as next_new_status_date
  FROM
    eventlog el
  ORDER BY el.event_date
  ) raw
GROUP BY next_new_status_date
```